# Vue,Js : Conditional search filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, vue.js

**Scenario:** **Select a table column from dropdown then select condition like `< | > | = | >= | <=` and then type the value in search box.**

The `column, condition, search input`:

```
// Select column name
<select class="dv-header-select" v-model="query.search_column">
    <option v-for="column in columns" :value="column">{{column}}</option>
</select>

// Select condition(<,>,<=,>=) 
<select class="dv-header-select" v-model="query.search_operator">
    <option v-for="(value, key) in operators" :value="key">{{value}}</option>
</select>

// Search value
<input type="text" class="dv-header-input" placeholder="Search"
    v-model="query.search_input">
```

Table row :

```
<tr v-for="row in filteredRow">
    <td v-for="(value, key) in row">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Js :

```
export default {



    data() {
        return {
        model: { data: [] },
        columns: {},
        query: {
            search_column: 'id',
            search_operator: 'equal',
            search_input: ''
        }
    },


    computed: {
      filteredRow: function(){

        // Values of column, condition, search string (E.g age > 20)
        console.log(this.query.search_column);
        console.log(this.query.search_operator);
        console.log(this.query.search_input);

        return this.model.data.filter((row) => {
        for(var key in row){
            if(String(row[key]).indexOf(this.query.search_input) !== -1){
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

How can i search the table ? Tried around but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of this:

```js
var test = {
  computed: {
    filteredRow: function() {
      return this.model.data.filter(row => {
        var value = row[this.query.search_column];
        switch (this.query.search_operator) {
          case "=": return value == this.query.search_input;
          case ">": return value > this.query.search_input;
          // ...
        }
      });
    }
  }
};

var vm = {
  model: {data: [{a: 1}, {a: 2}] },
  query: {search_column: "a", search_operator: ">", search_input: 1 }
};

console.log(test.computed.filteredRow.call(vm));
```

Missing: Type checks, type conversions, other operators, input sanitation.

Comment: Thanks, Its giving me an exception `Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"`.

Comment: My bad, try again.

Comment: The exception is gone but the table is empty, actually `<tr>` have `v-for`, and its on the `filteredRow`. Updated the question. And thanks

Comment: That's why I said "along the lines of". I haven't provided a drop-in replacement for your function. I have provided a function that does what you seem to want (i.e. "filtering an array of objects by a user-selectable property with a user-selectable operator" - correct me if I'm wrong here). You need to adapt it to your situation.